# Not working with package name and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, package, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app uploaded to the play store. The package is: **com.pathapp** but then with gradle are generated two apk, **com.path** debug and release (without app). Now I want to integrate firebase, but I do not know what name of the app is what I have to put in firebase, if com.path or com.pathapp in order to have a well constructed google-services.json file.

If I change the original package of the directories from pathapp to path, there would be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.00"
}
}
```

`applicationId` in the gradle is your package name.

So you need to add that in the firebase console.

In the above example, the package name is `com.example`. Likewise, check your gradle.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Play Store you can see the package name of your current app. Use this, or you won't be able to upload in the store.

To see the package name is linked with your Firebase, open your project in Firebase and click on Settings, here you will see the package name of the app.

If is not the same:

-There, you can see an option to add a new app. Click the button and add a new app with your new package: com.pathapp

-Finally, you have to download the new google-services.json and add it in your project, deleting the old one if you still have it.